# New to JWT, need to find what middleware to use to validate the JWT token

Tags: c#, .net, jwt, openid-connect

Have a .net framework API that is currently using SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider.   It is now requested that we use OpenId and JWT to provide API authorization.  JWT token will be created via an authorization server, just need to validate issuer, audience, client_id on API end.   Having trouble finding the right Middleware to inject the validate token logic.

Tried the following:

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
            Provider = new JWTAuthorizationServerProvider() //new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
        };

        //app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

        OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions options = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();
        
        app.Map("/api", api =>
        {
            
            api.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = false,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"])) 
            };

        });

        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    }
```

The TokenValidationParameters is not part of the OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions.   I guessing this isn't the right authentication method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JwtSecurityTokenHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtsecuritytokenhandler.validatetoken?view=msal-web-dotnet-latest) class can be used to validate JWT. It has the TokenValidationParameters can be sent as parameter to ValidateToken Method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the JwtBearer handler to validate JWT tokens in an ASP.NET core application.

Sample code

```
services.AddAuthentication("token")
    .AddJwtBearer("token", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://identityservice.mysecure.nu";
        //...
    });


/...

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

What does JwtBearer do? It converts, validates incoming tokens and creates a User object based on the token.

[image]

If you need to troubleshoot JwtBearer, then I have a blog post about that here
[Troubleshooting JwtBearer authentication problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/)